# File handling mechanism in unix

Tags: unix

Could someone please explain me the file handling mechanism in Unix. If you rm files, you don't see an immediate change in disk free, but a slow current of freeing space. What are the reasons behind this behavior?

edit. I had a drive which was maxed out to 100%, I did rm -r some terabytes data but rather than seeing immediate change with df, I saw a slowly rising value in available disk space.

Comment: can you please provide an example or some more info on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be because the files are reference counted in *nix. `rm` removes the file from the directory tree but as long as there's an reference (i.e. an open file descriptor), it'll still be there even though there are no links left to the inode. This can be the reason for the slow rising value of available disk space as the files are cleaned as the handles are getting closed.